# Wrong projected position opengl with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, opengl, augmented-reality

I have a program in which I would like to project a 3d model on the scene using OpenCV and OpenGL. For this, I first get the 3x3 homopgrahy matrix using `cv2.findHomography()` and followed by `cv2.decomposeHomographyMat()` which return rotation and translation vector for me. It returns four possible arrays for each rotation and translation. After trying with the four arrays, each of them didn't change much to the projected point and was almost the same.

Then I compute the model view matrix (for OpenGL projection) by the rotation and translation vector that I get from the decomposition of homography but turns out the projected position is not correct. I doubt that the transformation from rotation and translation to model view matrix is wrong, please do help to take a look at it. Please do suggest a better method to do the transformation if there is one, thanks in advance.

*For the not correct position I mean it didn't project right onto the desired position instead projected on another position.

Here is the code:

```
...
homography_matrix, _ = cv2.findHomography(set_point1, set_point2,cv2.RANSAC,5)

# homography matrix value
[[ 6.49469641e-01  3.05514095e-02  2.22136754e+02]
 [-1.44896635e-02  5.80832563e-01  1.22989887e+02]
 [ 9.15442047e-05 -6.03875028e-05  1.00000000e+00]]


# compute model view matrix
num, rvec, tvec, _ = cv2.decomposeHomographyMat(homography_matrix, calibration_matrix)
rmtx = np.array(rvec)
tmtx = np.array(tvec)

# rotation vector
(array([[ 0.9975257 ,  0.06259469, -0.03200593],
        [-0.0590899 ,  0.99316086,  0.10069705],
        [ 0.03809014, -0.09855667,  0.99440219]]), 
 array([[ 0.9975257 ,  0.06259469, -0.03200593],
        [-0.0590899 ,  0.99316086,  0.10069705],
        [ 0.03809014, -0.09855667,  0.99440219]]), 
 array([[ 0.97572152,  0.09882652,  0.19545034],
        [-0.08918155,  0.99435029, -0.05756872],
        [-0.20003542,  0.03874048,  0.97902248]]), 
 array([[ 0.97572152,  0.09882652,  0.19545034],
        [-0.08918155,  0.99435029, -0.05756872],
        [-0.20003542,  0.03874048,  0.97902248]]))

# translation vector
(array([[ 0.33814957],
        [-0.10127911],
        [ 0.6865044 ]]), 
 array([[-0.33814957],
        [ 0.10127911],
        [-0.6865044 ]]), 
 array([[0.11881547],
        [0.0624517 ],
        [0.76017995]]), 
 array([[-0.11881547],
        [-0.0624517 ],
        [-0.76017995]]))

view_matrix = np.array([[rmtx[0][0][0],rmtx[0][0][1],rmtx[0][0][2],  tmtx[0][0]],
                        [rmtx[0][1][0],rmtx[0][1][1],rmtx[0][1][2],  tmtx[0][1]],
                        [rmtx[0][2][0],rmtx[0][2][1],rmtx[0][2][2],  tmtx[0][2]],
                        [0.0       ,0.0       ,0.0       ,1.0    ]])

view_matrix = np.transpose(view_matrix)

...
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
gluPerspective(45, (width / height), 0.1, 50.0)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()
glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-10.0)
glMultMatrixd(view_matrix)
glRotatef(angle,0,1,0)
```

Example output:
[image]

Comment: all the values of all the variables would be useful to see... and some pictures that show "strange" things

Comment: Sure, I have edited the question and added the value. For the picture, due to some privacy issue, I am not able to show that. By strange I mean it didn't project right onto the desired position.

Comment: you've noticed that decomposeHomographyMat returns four different solutions and it can't tell which is the right one. try them all.

Comment: Yes, I have tried them all as mentioned in the question. But still, none of them is correct.

Comment: hmmm ok, I missed that. what handedness is used in OpenGL coordinate systems? OpenCV is right-handed, x right, y down, z far, generally. -- you aren't doing this to single images, but to video, right? how does the thing behave? do you notice a pattern?

Comment: Yea it's right-handed in OpenGL. Yes, I do it for video, it kinda sticks to the middle of the window (slightly right to the middle).

Comment: `glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-10.0)` means you're looking at the motion from far away. your calculated translation vectors are less than 1 in magnitude. I would expect the motion to be smallish. what did you expect it to be? -- I'm having to imagine here because I don't get to see any stuff. that's hard. consider figuring out how to make your situation showable.

Comment: I have added the image of the result. Please do ignore the texture of the model since its not complete yet and some of the other mess cause I filter out some privacy stuff. The object should be right on the QR code position there. And yes, it was very huge if I didn't set the value to -10.0.

Comment: scale the model instead.